# Docker. Create directory in container after docker-compose up and give it r/w permissions

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

How to create another `/tmp` directory, for example, in the same container and give it `r/w` permissions?

docker-compose.yml:

```
nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    command: nginx -g "daemon off;"
    networks:
      - network
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using only docker-compose without Dockerfile, can be done this way:

You can get into container, like this:

```
docker exec -ti $(docker ps --filter name='nginx' --format "{{ .ID }}")
```

Then, inside the container, you can run:

```
mkdir /tmp2
chmod 755 /tmp2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes, we are not using Dockerfile, but can we do it automatically in "command" line of the .yml file?

Comment: Never did it, but seems possible https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/205

Answer (score 5):

You can create a directory or perform any other action by defining it in a `Dockerfile`. In the same directory as your docker-compose.yml create a Dockerfile:

```
touch Dockerfile
```

Add to your *Dockerfile* following line:

```
RUN mkdir /tmp2
RUN chmod 755 /tmp2
```

to the docker-compose.yaml add build information:

```
nginx:
      image: nginx
      build: .
      ports:
        - 80:80
      volumes:
        - ./volumes/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      command: nginx -g "daemon off;"
      networks:
        - network
```

Comment: Please see https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/ how to go on after this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Simply just add a volume with the directory you wish to create and it would be created automatically during startup

```
nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./volumes/hosted-direcotry/hosted-sub-direcotry:/etc/created-direcotry/created-sub-directory/
    command: nginx -g "daemon off;"
    networks:
      - network
```

Comment: I can't speak for everyone, but I'm here to figure out how to create non-persistent directories. If you mount the volume, it will persist reboots.